# how to use Azure Key Vault for Kubernetes

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have Azure Pipeline where we are connecting to downstream and one of our developer used password in configmap as a plan test.

Can some one please tell me how I can use the existing Key-Vault to stored that password and refer in my Pipeline?

Comment: I'm confused.  The title says you want to use AKV secrets from K8s and your question is about using a secret in AKV from Azure Pipeline.

Comment: I apology CSharpRocks if I made any confusion. So my title is correct but I am using Azure Pipeline for multiple env deployment in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference your KeyVault in your pipeline and provide access to it.

Here is a good article regarding your question - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops

Comment: Hi Oleh Tarasenko,   Above link is useful but let me put my question more specific. I have a shared KeyVault where I can ask my Infra admin to add password in KV but my actual question is how I am going to reference it in my Pipeline. I have 4 env (dev/test/uat/prod) where we have my application deployed on K8s cluster. So if I will get these value in AKV then how I am going to reference them? what is the line of code?